# Referring to an Eloquent model from package

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to use an Eloquent model inside the `Sentry` package (this could've been any package).

I've refered to it using `use App\Models\User;` in the top, and `User::` when I need to call it.

However, I am getting this error: `Class 'App\Models\User' not found`

What am I doing wrong?

The current code is here: http://paste.laravel.com/H19

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? Sentry uses its own `user` model by default, if you want to change the model then look into the `vendor\cartalyst\sentry\src\config\config.php` file, there you can change the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume thath your models are in the App part of the application.
In laravel, the App namespace is the top level namespace (the default one).

So to call your models, you have to call \User (because \ refer to the top level namespace)

Alternatively you can do:

```
use \User as User
```

And then you can call it User instead of \User